# Запись в файл происходит в обратном порядке

Tags: c++

Есть код, в нем загадывается некоторое число, а потом пользователь пытается его угадать. Все корректные попытки, как правильные, так и нет, записываются в файл последовательно.
Так же, при вводе любого текста вместо числового значения, программа выходит (так и задумано).
Но, если пользователь сделал несколько попыток и не угадал число, то попытки записываются в файл корректно. В случае, если пользователь угадал число с некоторой попытки, то история попыток записывается снизу вверх, т.е. победная попытка оказывается на самом верху. Метод записи `ios::app`, который, по идеи, должен писать в конец файла. Пересмотрел код, но все равно не могу понять, почему в случае победы, записи в файле инвертированы.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> // подключаем функции ввода-вывода
#include <fstream> // подключаем функции чтения-записи в файл

using namespace std; // объявляем пространство имен

int num, generated_num, user_num;
void Match()
{   
    generated_num = rand() % num;
    cout << "Enter any number from 0 to " << num << ": ";
    cin >> user_num;
    ofstream output("output.txt", ios::app);
    if (cin.fail() || user_num < 0)
    {
        cout << "Cheating! Only positive numbers allowed!\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (user_num == generated_num)
    {
        output << user_num << " ";
        cout << "You won!\n";
    }
    else if (user_num > num)
    {
        cout << "\nThis number is not allowed!\n";
        Match();
    }
    else
    {
        output << user_num << " ";
        cout << "Try again!\n";
        Match();
    }
    output.close();
    cout << output.is_open();
}

int main()
{
    ifstream input_file("data.txt", ios::in);
    if (input_file.is_open())
    {
        while (input_file.good())
        {
            input_file >> num;;
        }

        input_file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No such file in directory!\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    ofstream output("output.txt", ios::trunc);
    output.close();
    Match();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась внесением операций по закрытию файла в тела else и else-if.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> // подключаем функции ввода-вывода
#include <fstream> // подключаем функции чтения-записи в файл

using namespace std; // объявляем пространство имен

int num, generated_num, user_num, counter = 0;
void Match()
{   
    ofstream output("output.txt", ios::app);
    generated_num = rand() % num;
    cout << "Enter any number from 0 to " << num << ": ";
    cin >> user_num;
    if (cin.fail() || user_num < 0)
    {
        cout << "Cheating! Only positive numbers allowed!\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (user_num == generated_num)
    {
        counter += 1;
        output << counter << ". " << user_num << "\n";
        output.close();
        cout << "You won!\n";
    }
    else if (user_num > num)
    {
        cout << "\nThis number is not allowed!\n";
        Match();
    }
    else
    {
        counter += 1;
        output << counter << ". " << user_num << "\n";
        output.close();
        cout << "Try again!\n";
        Match();
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream input_file("data.txt", ios::in);
    if (input_file.is_open())
    {
        while (input_file.good())
        {
            input_file >> num;;
        }

        input_file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No such file in directory!\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    ofstream output("output.txt", ios::trunc);
    output.close();
    Match();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас неверная структура. Вы использовали рекурсию, и в этой рекурсивно вызываемой функции каждый раз заново открывали уже открытый файл! (кстати, эта же ерунда у вас осталась в ветке

```
else if (user_num > num)
```

тут вы файл не закрываете. Результат - записанные данные, хранившиеся в буферах, сбрасывались в обратном порядке. При выходе с помощью `exit()` файлы, по-видимому, закрывались в порядке открытия (деструкторы локальных объектов при `exit()` не вызываются).

Вынесите свой `output` из `Match()` вовсе - например, передавайте его в функцию, или сделайте глобальным...